# Using GCR As Helm Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to use Google Container Registry as an Helm repo? 
I had success pushing charts to GCR, however when I try to add the repo using helm, I get an error"

```
Error: looks like "https://gcr.io/********" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Is that something to expect? I am doing

```
helm repo add reponame https://gcr.io/***** --username user-name --password *****
```

Comment: Does this [thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5861#issuecomment-503023681)  answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself - but it did not work. Instead, I found this plugin:

`https://github.com/hayorov/helm-gcs`

This allows you to use GCS as a helm repository. Quick setup/usage:

```sh
$ helm plugin install https://github.com/hayorov/helm-gcs.git

# Init a new repository
$ helm gcs init gs://bucket/path

# Add your repository to Helm
$ helm repo add repo-name gs://bucket/path

# Push a chart to your repository
$ helm gcs push chart.tar.gz repo-name

# Update Helm cache
$ helm repo update

# Fetch the chart
$ helm fetch repo-name/chart

# Remove the chart
$ helm gcs rm chart repo-name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chartmuseum](https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum). With chartmuseum you can configure any remote backend (GCS, S3) etc, Chartmuseum and your backend combined act as a chart repository with all the operations supported.

Also, chartmuseum is managed by helm. So, it's constantly being updated and is properly managed.